# Issue with Apache Hudi Update and Delete Operation on Parquet S3 File

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-emr, apache-hudi, apache-iceberg

Here I am trying to simulate updates and deletes over a Hudi dataset and wish to see the state reflected in Athena table. We use EMR, S3 and Athena services of AWS.

1. Attempting Record Update with a withdrawal object

```py
withdrawalID_mutate = 10382495
updateDF = final_df.filter(col("withdrawalID") == withdrawalID_mutate) \ 
    .withColumn("accountHolderName", lit("Hudi_Updated"))  
    
updateDF.write.format("hudi") \
    .options(**hudi_options) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save(tablePath) 
    
hudiDF = spark.read \
    .format("hudi") \
    .load(tablePath).filter(col("withdrawalID") == withdrawalID_mutate).show()
```

Shows the updated record but it is actually appended in the Athena table. Probably something to do with Glue Catalogue?

2. Attempting Record Delete

```py
deleteDF = updateDF #deleting the updated record above 
    
deleteDF.write.format("hudi") \ 
    .option('hoodie.datasource.write.operation', 'upsert') \
    .option('hoodie.datasource.write.payload.class', 'org.apache.hudi.common.model.EmptyHoodieRecordPayload') \
    .options(**hudi_options) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save(tablePath)
```

still reflects the deleted record in the Athena table

Also tried using `mode("overwrite")` but as expected it deletes the older partitions and keeps only the latest.

Comment: Could you provide the hudi_options  details?

Comment: `hudiOptions01 = {
'hoodie.table.name': tableName,
'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'upsert',
'hoodie.datasource.write.table.type': 'COPY_ON_WRITE',
'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': primaryKeyColumn,
'hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field': partitionColumn,
}`

Comment: `hudiOptions02 = {
'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable': 'true',
'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table': tableName,
'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.jdbcurl': 'jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000',
'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.assume_date_partitioning': 'true',
'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields': partitionColumn,
}`

Comment: Since comment box does not letting me post the complete json at once, I made two splits above.

Comment: Could you also share two sample records? Are you not providing ``"hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field"``?

Comment: Also what is your `partitionColumn` value?

Comment: I'am facing this same issue, did your issue got resolved ? If yes can you please share the how did you got it resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

In your deleteDF.write call you are setting the write operation to be `upsert`  which will upsert the record and not delete it.

Try change this

```
.option('hoodie.datasource.write.operation', 'upsert')
```

to

```
.option('hoodie.datasource.write.operation', 'delete')
```

This would delete the record.